# How to add user input from a text box to a list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, user-input

I'm trying to add input from a text box to a list in HTML. I've tried a few things and searches other stack overflow questions and got to the code below. The user input works, it just doesn't output to the list. Overall what I want the code to do is have the list display all the items that get typed into the text box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


  <script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {

    var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";


    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}

</script>

<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list'>
  <li> <b>Topics</b></li> 
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to append a `string`, not a `node`.
*The appendChild() method appends a node as the last child of a node.*

Answer (score 6):

Since you are trying to append *htmlString* into the element try with

[**`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
  var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
  document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list'>
  <li> <b>Topics</b></li> 
</ul>
```

**OR:** Using [**`Element.innerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
  var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += li;
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list'>
  <li> <b>Topics</b></li> 
</ul>
```

Though I prefer using [**`Document.createElement()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the HTML element which is allowed as parameter by [**`Node.appendChild()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = text;
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list'>
  <li> <b>Topics</b></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `document.createElement()` which creates the HTML element specified by tagName

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = text;

  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list'>
  <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I run the snippet on here the code works fine, but when I spy it over to my code editor it fails. Is there a way to see the full code with the updated part?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. There are no errors it just doesn't output the text from the text box to the list. The snippet on this website works fine though.

Comment: @MaxMuchnick No worries

Comment: Is there a way I can find the full updated code? When I copy the snippet and paste it over my old code it doesn't work so I must be copying it wrong.